# Promise chain with delay does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, delay, es6-promise, chaining

I need to chain promises back to back with a delay in between but it's not working. All the promises seem to resolve at the same time.

Here is a simplified example that does not seem to work.

```
function delayPromise() {
    const delay = 500;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    });
}

const data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
const promiseChain = Promise.resolve();

data.forEach(function(datum) {
    promiseChain
    .then(delayPromise)
    .then(delayPromise)
    .then(function(){
        // all of these are logged at the same time!
        console.log(`Datum logged: ${datum}`);
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Your promise chains are working fine, but you have seven of them all starting at the same time.  CRice's answer is essentially showing you how to append more `.then(delayPromise)` to end up with a single chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are all logged at the same time because you are always chaining off of the base promise, `promiseChain`, without re-assigning it. That is, since you never re-assign that value, you're always starting a new chain from the same `Promise.resolve`.

To change that, just make sure to reset the `promiseChain` variable with the new promise you get from the `.then` chain you set up. EG:

```
promiseChain = promiseChain
    .then(delayPromise)
    // ... so on
```

*Make sure `promiseChain` is declared with `let` or that won't work*

Here's your example with that fix. Note that now they all log with a delay in between each:

```js
function delayPromise() {
    const delay = 500;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    });
}

const data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
let promiseChain = Promise.resolve();

data.forEach(function(datum) {
    promiseChain = promiseChain
    .then(delayPromise)
    .then(delayPromise)
    .then(function(){
        // These are all logged with a delay between each!
        console.log(`Datum logged: ${datum}`);
    });
});
```

Comment: This works but I prefer the more canonical approach using `reduce()`: `data.reduce((chain, datum) => chain.then(delayPromise).then(...), Promise.resolve())`

Comment: Yes!. It works. Just spent hours trying to force insert DB models sequentially and completely overlooked that `.then()`  does not overwrite the original promise.

Also, `reduce()` works but I find that `forEach` is easier to fallow